# How to get the url of the requesting site with pyramid

Tags: python, httprequest, pyramid

I'm writing a small app with pyramid. One view serves files with a FileResponse. What I want to do is limiting those files to certain domains.

If this site http://www.example.com/index.html includes a file like:

```
<img src="http://myapp.com/servethisfile" />
```

I want to know the domain of the site which requests a file from my app. (example.com)

The limitation has to be done within the view as if will change during runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser sends the referrer in the HTTP headers when doing a request. It's easily hackable though and I would not rely on this to protect something important.

In Pyramid, you can access that header in `request.referrer`.

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.referer

Comment: yes that worked. I would like to mention something because I had to find it out myself. If the request.referrer and request.url would be same (referrer is the app itself) then request.referrer is set to None.